# How to Add new listitem to List<string> in settings.settings

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I am trying to add new list item to settings.settings file. I have modified my settings.settings file as below

[image]

and on button click i have the following code:

```
 private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string tempConString = "server='.\sqlexpress';database='somedatabasename';Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
 Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString.Add(tempConString);
                                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

i am getting NullReferenceException with message Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I want to save multiple strings to  Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString

Comment: look ...the value is empty!

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890271/how-to-save-a-liststring-on-settings-default

Comment: sorry, i have read the post which you have given. by reading that post only i have modified my code, but i am getting nullreference error. how to overcome this is my question.

Comment: How did you get `System.Collections.Generic.List` to show up in your settings? Even when I click "browse" I don't see a `System.Collections`.

Comment: i followed the instructions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890271/how-to-save-a-liststring-on-settings-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve desired behavior you should follow the Accepted Answer of the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890271/how-to-save-a-liststring-on-settings-default). I don't understand why a wrong answer is so upvoted.

Never the less, just pick `System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection` from Type DropDown and insert your values from new lines.
And where you want to use it do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Settings.Default.test.Cast<string>().ToList().FirstOrDefault());
```

Everything was in that post, to be honest.

Follow instructions from http://csharphelper.com/blog/2011/08/use-a-setting-that-contains-a-string-collection-in-c/

Comment: can you please help me how to add a new string from code behind, when i tried properties.settings.default.constring.add("somestring") giving me error

Comment: What kind of error? What does the error say? Code behind of the aspx page? Code behind of WPF view? Please, provide more information.

Comment: i am using in winforms application. ".cs" file, http://csharphelper.com/blog/2011/08/use-a-setting-that-contains-a-string-collection-in-c/ this is what exactly i am trying to do but i am still getting error "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source"

Comment: Ok, I was testing it with WPF app. But basically in winforms it's the same. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6611972/5246145. Currently I've tested it in WinForms application and the steps are the same as described, the only difference, manually introduce something from designer, so the Collection would be initialized.

Comment: thanks it worked now, the mistake i was doing is i have initially set "connectionString" to type "string" and later modified the type to "System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" so it was giving error after that i have created a new name "conString" and specified type as "System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" and updated my code and followed instructions from the link http://csharphelper.com/blog/2011/08/use-a-setting-that-contains-a-string-collection-in-c/ now its working.